# how to call a javascript or jquery function after the previous function call gets executes completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, synchronous

i am having a simple `jquery loop`. in this loop i am calling a `jquery function`. but whats happening here is that the `functions` are getting called `paralally`. when the `previous function` call still `running`, the loop is calling the `same function` again. as a result of which the output is coming `properly` only for the last `function` call. how can i call a `jquery` or a `javascript` function once the previous `function` call gets executed `completely`?

here is my loop

```
$("select.project_dp").each(function(index) {
  populate_tasks($(this));
});
```

and here is the function definition.

```
 function populate_tasks(project_dp) {
   alert("asdfsdfasdfa");
   project_id = project_dp.val();

   next_td = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).find("select");
   customer_div = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".customer_hidden");
   start_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".start_time");
   end_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".end_time");
   hrs_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".hrs_dp");
   mins_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".mins_dp");

    next_td.empty();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/log_times/populate_tasks',
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {proj_id: project_id },
      success:function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    next_td.empty();
    customer_div.val(data.cust_id) 

    jQuery.each(data.tasks,function(i, v) {
         next_td.append($('<option value="'+ data.tasks[i]["id"] +'">'+data.tasks[i]["name"] +'</option>'));


       });



       if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Duration") {
          hrs_dp.prop('disabled', false);
          mins_dp.prop('disabled', false);
          start_time.prop('disabled', true);
          end_time.prop('disabled', true);
       } else if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Start & End Time") { 
          hrs_dp.prop('disabled', true);
          mins_dp.prop('disabled', true);
          start_time.prop('disabled', false);
          end_time.prop('disabled', false);
       } 

      }
    });

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback function:

```
function myCallback() {
    alert("Complete!");
}

$("select.project_dp").each(function(index) {
  populate_tasks($(this), myCallback);
});
```

You then just need to call `callbackFunction` at the end of your `populate_tasks()` function when all is done.

```
callbackFunction();
```

You need your `populate_tasks()` function to accept the new parameter:

```
 function populate_tasks(project_dp, callbackFunction) {
   alert("asdfsdfasdfa");
   project_id = project_dp.val();

   next_td = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).find("select");
   customer_div = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".customer_hidden");
   start_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".start_time");
   end_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".end_time");
   hrs_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".hrs_dp");
   mins_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".mins_dp");
next_td.empty();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/log_times/populate_tasks',
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: {proj_id: project_id },
  success:function(data) {
console.log(data);  
next_td.empty();
customer_div.val(data.cust_id) 

jQuery.each(data.tasks,function(i, v) {
     next_td.append($('<option value="'+ data.tasks[i]["id"] +'">'+data.tasks[i]["name"] +'</option>'));


   });



   if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Duration") {
      hrs_dp.prop('disabled', false);
      mins_dp.prop('disabled', false);
      start_time.prop('disabled', true);
      end_time.prop('disabled', true);
   } else if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Start & End Time") { 
      hrs_dp.prop('disabled', true);
      mins_dp.prop('disabled', true);
      start_time.prop('disabled', false);
      end_time.prop('disabled', false);
   } 

//  Call your callback function when this function completes
//
callbackFunction();
}

});

}
```

You would have to call populate_tasks() and pass a paremter that points to the callback function to be executed, so if we have a function called `myCallback` that you want to run when `populate_tasks()` ends:

```
populate_tasks($(this), myCallback);
```

The `callback_function` is really just a pointer that points to whatever function you pass, in this case `myCallback`

As for the code that should be in the callback function...that's up to you, I've no idea what you intend to do when the `populate_tasks()` function completes.

Comment: what code should be present in "callbackFunction" and what code should be present in "myCallback" function?

Comment: No offence but the code is pretty messy, you should try and format it ia little better before posting.

Comment: i'm not sure if this will solve his problem. the functions still be  called paralally, or am i wrong?

Comment: This won't work because $.each executes `populate_tasks()` regardless of having a callback or not. You need to move to next index inside `populate_tasks()`

Comment: its not working. callback is calling but of no use. still the functions are getting called parallally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can solve your problem using queue or promises.
Another approach can be a recoursive function similar to this:

```
 var i = 0;
 var tasks = [];
 $("select.project_dp").each(function(index) {
  tasks.push($(this));
}); 

 populate_tasks(tasks[i]);

 function populate_tasks(project_dp) {
 if(i <= tasks.length){
   alert("asdfsdfasdfa");
   project_id = project_dp.val();

   next_td = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).find("select");
   customer_div = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".customer_hidden");
   start_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".start_time");
   end_time = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".end_time");
   hrs_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".hrs_dp");
   mins_dp = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).next( "div" ).find(".mins_dp");

    next_td.empty();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/log_times/populate_tasks',
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {proj_id: project_id },
      success:function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    next_td.empty();
    customer_div.val(data.cust_id) 

    jQuery.each(data.tasks,function(i, v) {
         next_td.append($('<option value="'+ data.tasks[i]["id"] +'">'+data.tasks[i]["name"] +'</option>'));


       });



       if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Duration") {
          hrs_dp.prop('disabled', false);
          mins_dp.prop('disabled', false);
          start_time.prop('disabled', true);
          end_time.prop('disabled', true);
       } else if (data.project.hrs_calc_criteria == "By Start & End Time") { 
          hrs_dp.prop('disabled', true);
          mins_dp.prop('disabled', true);
          start_time.prop('disabled', false);
          end_time.prop('disabled', false);
       } 
                i ++;
        populate_tasks(tasks[i]);
      }
    });
}
      }
```

Basically you first run the function on first element once it is completed you execute your function on second element ecc... until tasks ends.